# Google Script to replace ImportRange formula that stopped working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help. My work uses a Google Form (absence request form) to collect employees time off/sick time information. On submit, that data goes into a Google Spreadsheet where the total time off is then calculated with a formula.

The employee charged of updating all employees time off uses a different google spreadsheet to do payroll. I was using the following formula to import the data from the absence request form sheet until it suddenly stopped working. My guess is that the data important became too big. There are currently 560 rows in the spreadsheet and 18 columns. 
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uZL7bMIiuOEpSbC0kk3rB_nkBAGb8Pf-opwl4FGovJ0/edit#gid=971834620", "'Form Responses 1'!B:P"), "Select Col1, Col4, Col5, Col11, Col14 where Col2 <> ''", 1)   [Note: I cannot share the spreadsheet listed in the formula]

Col1 is email, Col4 is first day off, Col5 is last day off, Col11 is total hours off, Col14 is the description of time off (personal, sick time, etc).

I tried to replace it by a script but keep on running into errors. I don't know a thing about Google Apps Scripts. I spent the last 3 days reading about them on here and trying to program something but nothing is working. Many of the scripts end up in timed out errors after a minute or two or not giving error messages at all and not working.

Other formulas run in the payroll sheet. Here's the link to a mock payroll sheet that has all of the elements: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y4baWrY0799dQPffXfD7oKCMISy7uai34wTRG5dtlfQ/edit?usp=sharing

My questions are:
1. Can the importrange formula be improved to work again? If so, what can I do to speed things up?
2. Can a script solve my formula issues and possibly speed up the calculation process(it sometimes takes an hour to do the entire sheet)
3. If a script can help, what would it be?

At this point I'm banging my head on the walls, so very open to trying anything!

This is the last script I tried and I got this error message: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 15, file "Code")

```
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Copy", functionName:"Copy"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Menu', submenu);  
}

function Copy() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1uZL7bMIiuOEpSbC0kk3rB_nkBAGb8Pf-opwl4FGovJ0'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Responses'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:O600'); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1f53bnAllY5LYgwyPY9X8oZJ5fMBbwpiB5CRglaw_iqM'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Data3forscript'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,16,38).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()
```

Comment: I think that the reason of the error might be that there is no sheet of ``Data3forscript`` in the Spreadsheet of ``1f53bnAllY5LYgwyPY9X8oZJ5fMBbwpiB5CRglaw_iqM``. And I think that when the values of ``data`` is put to the sheet, an error related to the range occurs. Because although ``data`` has 600 rows and 15 columns, the script uses 16 rows and 38 columns. Please make them the same length.

Comment: Tanaike, what do you mean there is no sheet of "data3script". That tab exists. I did make the D lowercase though. Data has 560 rows currently but it will keep on increasing as more people fill out the absence form. I do not understand how to make things the same length.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Although I'm not sure about ``line 15, file "Code"`` in your question, if the error of ``Cannot call method "getRange" of null`` occurs at ``ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,16,38).setValues(data)``, when the sheet with the sheet name of ``data3script`` is not existing in the spreadsheet of ``1f53bnAllY5LYgwyPY9X8oZJ5fMBbwpiB5CRglaw_iqM``, ``ts`` becomes null. By this, I thought that such error occurs.

Comment: About the data length, you can retrieve the length like ``data.length`` and ``data[0].length`` for rows and columns, respectively. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: @AlixL. How are you getting on with your Google sheets problem? Have you resolved it, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: @Tedinoz I gave up. I found a roundaboutway solution: I created a tab in my initial spreadsheet, and made sure all the data I needed was in plain format in there, not formulas. Then I created a duplicate of my destination spreadsheet, and that sped up the query and is working fine for now. I don't have time at the moment to investigate more so that will have to do. Thanks for checking!